# How to loop through a DataFrame containing 80k+ rows

Tags: python, pandas, loops

This question might have other answers but I could not figure out how to apply them on my current code.

I have to iterate through the DataFrame and modify certain column values as shown below:

**NOTE:** All of the columns are strings. The ones with _Length contain the length in int of the columns containing strings.

```
for col in range(0, 200):
if df['Partial_Input_Length'][col] < 50:
    df['Full_Input'][col] = df['Partial_Input'][col] + " " + df['Input5'][col] + " " + df['Input6'][col]
else:
    df['Full_Input'][col] = df['Partial_Input'][col]
```

This was used when I used a testing DataFrame containing only 200 rows. If I use `for col in range(0, 80000):` in the 80k rows DataFrame, it takes a huge amount of time until every operation is done.

I also tried out with `itertuples()` in this way:

```
for col in df.itertuples():
if col.Partial_Input_Length < 50:
    col.Full_Input = col.Partial_Input + " " + col.Input5 + " " + col.Input6
else:
    col.Full_Input = col.Partial_Input
```

But after running it, I get the following error.

> File "", line 23, in 
>       col.Full_Input = col.Partial_Input + " " + col.Input5 + " " + col.Input6
>
> AttributeError: can't set attribute

Moreover, I tried with `iterrows()` like this:

```
for index, col in df.iterrows():
    if df['Partial_Input_Length'][index] < 50:
        df['Full_Input'][index] = df['Partial_Input'][index] + " " + df['Input5'][index] + " " + df['Input6'][index]
    else:
        df['Full_Input'][index] = df['Partial_Input'][index]
```

But the code above is taking huge amounts of time, as well.

Is it normal that every time I run these iterations on a big dataframe it takes a lot of time or am I doing something wrong?

I am quite a newbie when it comes to iterating in python. Therefore, what method should I use for the quickest iteration time and which fits on what I am trying to use it for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without looping:

```
df['Full_Input'] = df['Partial_Input'].str.cat(df['Input5'], sep=" ").str.cat(df['Input6'], sep=" ")
df['Full_Input'] = np.where(df['Partial_Input_Length'].str.len() > 50, df['Partial_Input'], df['Full_Input'])
```

Comment: Awesome! But how about this other case when I also have `try` and `except`? `for col in range(0,80000):
    try:
        my_sentences = [s for s in sentence_list if len(s) + df['No_Input4_Length'][col] < 60]
        df['Input4_OK(hopefully)'][col] = np.random.choice(my_sentences)
    except ValueError:
        print("Oops")`

Comment: Looks like there's a lot going on with that one - probably best to post another question with a full reproducible example.

Comment: I know, right? Thank you for your help, nonetheless!

Answer (score 1):

1. first of all you should not be modifying the elements that you are iterating over
2. almost all iter* functions in pandas will return read-only items, so setting anything on them will not work

to do what you want, I use apply or run a loop, that will call a function that will return a dict with the changes you want to be done and then either remake the entire dataframe or do a merge

something like

```
# if your modification is more simple then a simple apply will also work

df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda x: f'{x.startDate.year}-{x.startDate.week}')

# if you want to do something more complex with all the items in the row
def foo(row):
    def mofification_code(item):
        return modified_item

    return {
        'primary_key': row.primary_key,
        'modified_data': modification_code(row.item)
    }

modified_data = [foo(row) for row in df.itertuples()]

# sometimes this may be sufficient,
new_df = pd.DataFrame(modified_data) 

# alternatively, you can do a merge with the original data
new_df = pd.merge(df, new_df, how='left', left_on='primary_key', right_on='primary_key')
```